# Autoloading externally compiled module at hotplug event

Tags: usb, kernel-modules, lan

I have a pretty outdated embedded linux driven system with v2.6.33.7 kernel, which came without USBNET and CDC_ETHER modules. I compiled those modules to be able to attach a certain USB-LAN stick, that works with the CDC driver, which is loaded by the USBNET module. Now I copied the modules to the folder `/lib/modules/2.6.33.7/kernel/drivers/net/usb`.

It is possible to load the cdc_ether module using `insmod` but `modprobe` gives me an error.
After insmodding the usbnet module, `dmesg`shows:
`usbnet: exports duplicate symbol usbnet_resume (owned by kernel)`.
Also if I try to unload the usbnet module I get the error:
`FATAL: Module usbnet is builtin`

After insmodding the cdc_ether module `dmesg` shows success:
`eth1: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-mxc-ehci.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device, fc:8f:c4:06:e8:9c
usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether`
If I start up cdc_ether module manually there is an ethernet adapter `eth1` available to the system, which in turn can be sucessfully configured using `ifconfig`.

How is it possible to autoload the module when the stick gets plugged in? I have had a look at the `udev` driver rules, which seem to load kernel modules, and also at the modules.* files in `/lib/modules/2.6.33.7/` ... no luck. What is the missing piece to get this working?

---

I just found out, looking in the compile time configuration file `/proc/config.gz` that the usbnet module was supposed to be builtin by the company that compiled my kernel as it is stated there `CONFIG_USB_USBNET=y`
 So I basically need to run the cdc_ether module when the stick is plugged in by a udev rule, right?

---

I was able to grab the `modules.*` files that have been built and put them into the old kernel folder `/lib/modules/2.6.33.7/`. The effect is, `modprobe` now knows the modules when trying to load them using modprobe.

---

Since usbnet module is built in, it runs right away from the startup. Only cdc_ether module needs to be started then. After getting modprobing to work I need hotplugging mechanism. For ease of coding I added cdc_ether to `/etc/modules`. The module is loaded at bootup.
I had the network configuration file `/etc/network/interfaces` edited properly bit the new interface `eth1` would never get its IP when it was brought up, because it was somehow already configured. So I added a udev rule which flushes the addresses of each eth-device that gets taken down.

```
#ACTION=="add",SUBSYSTEM=="usb",DRIVER=="cdc_ether",RUN+="/sbin/modprobe cdc_ether"
ACTION=="add",SUBSYSTEM=="net",RUN+="/sbin/ifup %k"
ACTION=="remove",SUBSYSTEM=="net",RUN+="/sbin/ifdown %k",RUN+="/sbin/ip addr flush %k"
```

I can't get the hotplug module loading to work, that's why I seem to have to stick with the loading at system startup.